# CoreData does not generate NSManagedObject for Swift 3

Tags: ios, xcode, core-data, swift3, codegen

`CoreData` code generation doesn't generate `NSManagedObject` subsclass for `swift3` for example: It creates `NSDate` properties instead of `Date`. Any idea how can I generate models for `Swift3`?

Note:- I have found nothing in `CoreData` Code Generation settings to switch language explicitly to `Swift 3` yet we can generate `Swift` models. But there are some classes which have been updated in `Swift 3`.

Comment: Select the model file in the navigator, select an entity, press ⌥⌘1 and check if Code Generation > Language is set to Swift.

Comment: Code Generation Language is set to Swift but my question is "Why CodeGen converts all `Date` properties to `NSDate`?"

Comment: I know but I suspected that Xcode had generated Objective-C classes.

Comment: If I get it correctly, I think it is saying about different configurations of code generation. right?

Comment: Nevertheless simply change the type manually. You can also change NSNumber to Swift related types `Bool`, `Int32` etc.

Answer (score 1):

A lot of property types still use subclasses of `NSObject`. You will most likely need to convert them manually.

For `NSDate` specifically you may use:

```
return (date as NSDate?) ?? nil
```

and

```
return (date as Date?) ?? nil
```

For easier usage you can create extensions on `Date` and `NSDate` to return the typecast values the way you want it. An alternative is to change the date fields in database to be something like `rawDate` and then create a property `date` that overrides both setter and getter and does the conversion to/from original property `rawDate`.

In any case these objects are not excluded in Swift 3, they are just replaced with newer types in most of the API.